# unknown PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

For no reason in my spring boot application , i keep having this error message

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [DELETE FROM SPRING_SESSION WHERE EXPIRY_TIME < ?]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'ecm_resume.spring_session' doesn't exist
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:234) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1402) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:620) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:850) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:905) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:915) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.lambda$cleanUpExpiredSessions$7(JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.java:590) ~[spring-session-jdbc-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.cleanUpExpiredSessions(JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.java:589) ~[spring-session-jdbc-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.session.jdbc.config.annotation.web.http.JdbcHttpSessionConfiguration.lambda$configureTasks$0(JdbcHttpSessionConfiguration.java:194) ~[spring-session-jdbc-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93) [spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_161]
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'ecm_resume.spring_session' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:944) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3978) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3914) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2530) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2683) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2495) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1903) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2124) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2058) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5158) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2043) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.lambda$update$0(JdbcTemplate.java:855) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:605) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
2018-10-12 12:27:00.006 ERROR 14032 --- [pool-1-thread-1] o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler    : Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [DELETE FROM SPRING_SESSION WHERE EXPIRY_TIME < ?]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'ecm_resume.spring_session' doesn't exist
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:234) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1402) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:620) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:850) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:905) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:915) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.lambda$cleanUpExpiredSessions$7(JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.java:590) ~[spring-session-jdbc-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.cleanUpExpiredSessions(JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.java:589) ~[spring-session-jdbc-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.session.jdbc.config.annotation.web.http.JdbcHttpSessionConfiguration.lambda$configureTasks$0(JdbcHttpSessionConfiguration.java:194) ~[spring-session-jdbc-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93) [spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_161]
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'ecm_resume.spring_session' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:944) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3978) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3914) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2530) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2683) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2495) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1903) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2124) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2058) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5158) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2043) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.lambda$update$0(JdbcTemplate.java:855) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:605) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
2018-10-12 12:28:00.006 ERROR 14032 --- [pool-1-thread-1] o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler    : Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [DELETE FROM SPRING_SESSION WHERE EXPIRY_TIME < ?]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'ecm_resume.spring_session' doesn't exist
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:234) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1402) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:620) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:850) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:905) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:915) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.lambda$cleanUpExpiredSessions$7(JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.java:590) ~[spring-session-jdbc-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.cleanUpExpiredSessions(JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.java:589) ~[spring-session-jdbc-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.session.jdbc.config.annotation.web.http.JdbcHttpSessionConfiguration.lambda$configureTasks$0(JdbcHttpSessionConfiguration.java:194) ~[spring-session-jdbc-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93) [spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_161]
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'ecm_resume.spring_session' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:944) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3978) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3914) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2530) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2683) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2495) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1903) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2124) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2058) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5158) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2043) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.lambda$update$0(JdbcTemplate.java:855) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:605) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

I have tried to see if it is my configurations that are wrong, but i don't see any errors

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3308/ecm_resume?useSSL=false&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC

spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=admin

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=10000
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=5
spring.datasource.tomcat.test-on-borrow=true

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update): with "create-drop" the database

# schema will be automatically created afresh for every start of application
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
# Naming strategy

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
# Allows Hibernate to generate SQL optimized for a particular DBMS
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

It comes always periodicaly

Comment: Looks like you have added the [Spring session library](https://spring.io/projects/spring-session) to your project. Do you need that library?

Comment: I personally removed that , but it looks like it may be in the cache in intellij

Comment: That appears to be the case, as the `spring_session` table is necessary when working with the Spring session library.  Additionally there are `org.springframework.session.*` related classes mentioned in the stacktrace. If you're using Maven, you could use `mvn dependency:tree` to see if there's a nested dependency towards the Spring session library.

Comment: That is Spring JDBC causing the problem ... nothing to do with JPA!

Comment: The problem was that i used session library g00glen00b was rigth about it

Answer (score 2):

Add this in *application.properties*

```
spring.session.store-type=jdbc
spring.session.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
spring.session.timeout.seconds=900
```

Same error as at [session table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53823174/how-to-initialize-schema-in-spring-sessiona-jdbc/59730830#59730830)

Answer (score 0):

The error message says:

```
Table 'ecm_resume.spring_session' doesn't exist
```

in your properties you have `spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false` which means the db structures won't be generated.  Set this property to true, and make sure the database schema is created on start up