# How to initialize schema in spring-session with JDBC

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-session

I'm using Spring Boot 2.0.x, Hibernate and Spring Session Jdbc with Mysql 5.7. 
I'm working under development environment, so Hibernate is configured to generate schemas every time:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

And it works fine, but I have a problem with Spring Session... 
I tried set `initialize-schema`, but it doesn't work.

```
spring.session.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
```

Is it possible to auto generate full schema (all entities and SPRING_SESSION)?

It doesn't work for me with MySQL and H2 (I tried `embedded` option)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm using 2.2.7.RELEASE with `spring.session.jdbc.initialize-schema=always` and `spring.session.store-type=jdbc` and the tables aren't being created.

Comment: @theGirrafish No, but I didn't try new version of spring-session. Maybe it has been fixed...

Answer (score 3):

I am describing the steps.It worked for me.

1- Add the dependency in your pom file.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

2-Add the sql file in your project with same path and same name Under "resources" file.

**PATH : /org/springframework/session/jdbc/schema-mysql.sql**

schema-mysql.sql

```
CREATE TABLE SPRING_SESSION (
    PRIMARY_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    SESSION_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    CREATION_TIME BIGINT NOT NULL,
    LAST_ACCESS_TIME BIGINT NOT NULL,
    MAX_INACTIVE_INTERVAL INT NOT NULL,
    EXPIRY_TIME BIGINT NOT NULL,
    PRINCIPAL_NAME VARCHAR(100),
    CONSTRAINT SPRING_SESSION_PK PRIMARY KEY (PRIMARY_ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SPRING_SESSION_IX1 ON SPRING_SESSION (SESSION_ID);
CREATE INDEX SPRING_SESSION_IX2 ON SPRING_SESSION (EXPIRY_TIME);
CREATE INDEX SPRING_SESSION_IX3 ON SPRING_SESSION (PRINCIPAL_NAME);

CREATE TABLE SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES (
    SESSION_PRIMARY_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    ATTRIBUTE_NAME VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    ATTRIBUTE_BYTES BLOB NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES_PK PRIMARY KEY (SESSION_PRIMARY_ID, ATTRIBUTE_NAME),
    CONSTRAINT SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES_FK FOREIGN KEY (SESSION_PRIMARY_ID) REFERENCES SPRING_SESSION(PRIMARY_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

I got the sql file from official spring github account.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/master/spring-session-jdbc/src/main/resources/org/springframework/session/jdbc/schema-mysql.sql

3-Add below properties into application.properties

```
spring.session.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
spring.session.jdbc.schema=classpath:org/springframework/session/jdbc/schema-mysql.sql
```

If it don't work again,please let me know.Like I said,It worked for me.
[image]

Comment: I have schema in mysql, I know how to connect etc. Hibernate dll-auto=create-drop works fine. I have a problem with `spring.session.jdbc.initialize-schema=always`, because it doesn't initialize SPRING_SESSION tables on application start. Is it possible at all?

Comment: Which version of Spring Boot are You use?

Comment: I use 2.0.4.RELEASE

Comment: I use 2.0.6.RELEASE and it doesn't work... 

`spring.session.jdbc.initialize-schema=always` `spring.session.jdbc.schema=classpath:org/springframework/session/jdbc/schema-mysql.sql` `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop`
`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect`

Comment: Your hibernate dialect is MySQL57Dialect.Are u sure it is true? As I know it is MySQLDialect.  If it is possible,Just create an empty schema in db with SQL "create schema example;" code for one time,than it will update it for every time.You opened and closed the project you wont be create any more.Also could you please update the question if a fail is occuring?

Comment: MySQL57Dialect is correct and it provide innodb to entities tables.

Comment: I used this and it worked. Then I realized I had a typo in my table sql. I dropped the tables and restarted the app and now it ignores the schema file.

Comment: Something to keep in mind is not to have @EnableJdbcHttpSession together with entries in *application.properties* , otherwise Spring Boot won't do its auto configuration.

Answer (score 3):

Try this setting in the *application.properties*

```
spring.session.store-type=jdbc
spring.session.jdbc.initialize-schema=always //spring will create required tables for us
spring.session.timeout.seconds=900
```